# Why do I get at run time error when looping into the next worksheet even though the code executed correctly for the first worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have come to a point in my coding where well asked google questions are just not helping me anymore. I have two For loops in my code. They execute correctly for the first Worksheet I set in the loop in my Workbook. However changing to the next Worksheet gives a runtime error:

- runtime error 13 if I use Application.Average
- runtime error 1004 if I use Application.WorksheetFunction.Average

What I am trying to do:
I have data from measurements. These are organized in the different Worksheets for different temperature ranges. I want to loop through the relevant columns in the relevant worksheets in my data to find the average values of these columns. In the end I would like to save the averages to my first Worksheet for the corresponding headers. (I haven't written any code for this last part yet.)

Any help is very much appreciated.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestAv()

    Dim ColCount As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim j, k, ColCount2, wsCount As Long
    Dim rngAv As Range
    Dim rngAverage As Double
    Dim Lr As Long

    Dim newBook As Workbook
    Dim firstSheet As Worksheet

    Set newBook = ActiveWorkbook
    Set firstSheet = newBook.Sheets(1)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' making firstSheet representable
    ColCount = newBook.Worksheets(2).Columns.Count ' all TCs should have been measured for the first temperature
    newBook.Worksheets(2).Activate
    Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(1, ColCount)).Copy
    firstSheet.Activate
    firstSheet.Range("B1").Select
    firstSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = True
    firstSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Temperaturen"
    firstSheet.Name = "Mittelwerte"
    ' calculating mean values in columns of Worksheets
    wsCount = newBook.Worksheets.Count
    For j = 2 To wsCount
        LastRow = firstSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Set ws = newBook.Worksheets(j)
        firstSheet.Range("A" & LastRow).Value = ws.Name
        ColCount2 = ws.Columns.Count
        ws.Activate
        Lr = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1
        For k = 2 To ColCount2
            Set rngAv = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, k), ws.Cells(Lr, k))
            rngAverage = Application.Average(rngAv)
            Cells(Lr + 2, k).Value = rngAverage
        Next k
        Set rngAv = Nothing
        Set ws = Nothing
    Next j
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ' Mean Values of TCs for different Temperatures in firstSheet
End Sub
```

Comment: Non-numeric values is the range to be averaged maybe?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but do you really need to calculate the average for all 16k columns? @BigBen - I always thought average excluded non-numeric values, but not sure about error values.

Comment: @SJR `Application.Average` seems to throw a type-mismatch error.

Comment: You also get RTE 13 if all values are blank so I reckon column 14320 or something probably has nothing in it!

Comment: `ColCount = newBook.Worksheets(2).Columns.Count` and `ColCount2 = ws.Columns.Count` will always return `16384` (or however many columns are in your version of Excel).

Answer (score 3):

- runtime error 13 if I use Application.Average

  `Application.Average` is *late-bound* and behaves like the worksheet function `AVERAGE`, i.e. by *returning* an error value when the result can't be evaluated. Because an error value can't be coerced into a `Double`, the assignment fails with a *type mismatch* error.

  You could capture the result into a `Variant`, check to see if it's an error value, *then* assign to a `Double`; use the `IsError` function to do this:

  ```
  Dim avgResult As Variant
  avgResult = Application.Average(...)

  If Not IsError(avgResult) Then
      rngAverage = avgResult
      'rngAverage is safe to use as a Double
  Else
      ' avgResult is a #VALUE! error. what now?
  End If
  ```
- runtime error 1004 if I use Application.WorksheetFunction.Average

  That's because `WorksheetFunction.Average` is *early-bound*, and handles errors in a way that is idiomatic to VBA: instead of *returning* an `Error` value, it *throws* a run-time error, which can then be handled with a normal `On Error` statement and error-handling subroutine.

The `Average` function is returning/throwing an error because the input it's given is invalid or contains errors - i.e. if you used the `AVERAGE` worksheet function on that data, you wouldn't be getting a `Double` result either. Fix the data.